# Can't open OneNote notebook from within a web part

Tags: 2013, web-part-zone, owa, onenote

I have a SharePoint 2013 site collection with the standard Documents library. I now open OneNote and create a new notebook via FILE > NEW > OTHER WEB LOCATIONS. Creating the OneNote Notebook works fine. After this, I add the Document Library to the start page of my site collection.

When I now (on my laptop with Office installed) go to the start page and click the OneNote file I get the following error message:

[image]

When I navigate to the library directly I can open the notebook without any errors in my client app.

When I open the Site Collection or the library directly on a system without Office installed (e.g. one of the SharePoint servers) the OneNote Notebook opens just fine using the Office We Apps.

Has anyone had this issue before that opening a OneNote Notebook in a document library that has been added to a page results in an error?

TIA,
Simon